# margin:auto не позиционирует элемент по центру

Tags: html, css

Как подружить IE с flexbox и выравниванием по центру (margin:auto).

```css
.b-bg {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 385px;
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto auto 124px auto;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-tabs li {
    padding: 0 40px;
}
.nav-tabs li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 6px 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-bg">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#smoodee">"SMOODEE"</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#team">КОМАНДА</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#partnership">СПІВПРАЦЯ</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что выравнивание с помощью `margin` допустимо к блочным элементам с известной шириной

```css
.b-bg {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 385px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.nav-tabs {
    background: green; /* for test */
    display: block; 
    width: 800px; /* for test */
    margin: auto auto 124px auto;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 40px;
}
.nav-tabs li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 6px 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-bg">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#smoodee">"SMOODEE"</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#team">КОМАНДА</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#partnership">СПІВПРАЦЯ</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Дополнение

Выравнивание по высоте – http://jsfiddle.net/w2dwLh2a/1/

Comment: При добавлении ширины, блок отцентровался, но не учитывает выравнивание по высоте

Comment: @wkornilow можете добавить `margin` что бы выровнять или вместо `display: block;` задать `inline-block` что бы выравнивать по вертикали.

Comment: Куда именно добавить inline-bock?

Comment: смотря что вы хотите выравнять по вертикали. Что вам нужно выравнять по высоте? Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: @wkornilow добавил в ответ, вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: по сути мне нужно, список #tabs выровнять по центру. В других браузерах это прекрасно работает margin:auto, если родителю указать display:flex. Но в IE все как обычно работает не так как у людей.

Comment: Вы уверены? В Safari Mac OS то же не работает ваш код

Comment: Странно. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex тут говорится что по идее flex должен там работать. Ладно, буду игратся с фолбеками

Comment: вы как бы не совсем верно flex команды (селекторы) обозначили , примерно выглядит так css: нужный блок-родитель {display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap;} вложеный-блок{order:1; flex:0 1 100%;} в общем писать долго - но в основном лучше применять то что уже описал я  и получится вот такое _> https://jsfiddle.net/mn9u5ggz/